# Python Change an int for a string

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a question with np.where

I have something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = [{'a1':'Marco 1'}, {'a1':'2'}, {'a1':'Marco 3'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)

df['a1'] = np.where(df['a1'].str.contains('Marco'), 'Marco', df['a1'])
```

And I want to know how to change the value in a1 == 2, for some string like 'Marco2'.

Comment: hi! Is any one of the answers below working? If so & if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 1):

try via `np.where()`:

```
df['a1']=np.where(df['a1'].str.isnumeric(),'Marco '+df['a1'],df['a1'])
```

**OR**

via boolean masking with loc accessor:

```
df.loc[df['a1'].str.isnumeric(),'a1']='Macro '+df.loc[df['a1'].str.isnumeric(),'a1']
```

**Note:** you can also use `str.isdigit()` method in place of `str.isnumeric()` method

Answer (score 0):

you can try `str.split`

```py
df['a1'] = 'Marco ' + df['a1'].str.split(r'Marco').str[-1]
df['a1']

# 0    Marco   1
# 1     Marco  2
# 2    Marco   3
# Name: a1, dtype: object
```

or `str.replace`

```py
df['a1'] = df['a1'].str.replace(r'(Marco)*\s*(\d+)', r'Marco \2')
df['a1']

# 0    Marco 1
# 1     Marco 2
# 2     Marco 3
# Name: a1, dtype: object
```